# ! Undefined control sequence. \picture ...#1{\csname end##1\endcsname }\pictur@

Tags: errors, diagrams, undefined

I'm trying to compile one book from source code to pdf but I've hit following error:

```
PATH=../pics:/home/wolf/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/bin:/home/wolf/bin:/home/wolf/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/bin:/home/wolf/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl asy -f pdf -tex pdftex c-sample.asy
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdfcsplain)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
 encTeX v. Jun. 2004, reencoding enabled.
The format: csplain <Apr. 2016>.
The cs-fonts are preloaded and A4 size implicitly defined.
The utf8->iso8859-2 re-encoding of Czech+Slovak alphabet activated by encTeX
(./c-sample_.tex (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/plain/graphics-pln/graphicx.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/plain/graphics-pln/miniltx.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
))))) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/plain/graphics-pln/picture.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/plain/graphics-pln/miniltx.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/plain/graphics-pln/autopict.sty))
! Undefined control sequence.
\picture ...#1{\csname end##1\endcsname }\pictur@ 
                                                  #1
l.54 \picture(
               60.225000, 52.831897)%
! Undefined control sequence.
\endpicture ->\@@endpicture 
                            \endgroup 
l.71 \endpicture
                %
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map} <./c-sample_0.pdf>] )
(see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/share/texmf-dist/font
s/type1/public/cs/csbx10.pfb></usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cs/csr10
.pfb></usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cs/csr7.pfb>
Output written on c-sample_.pdf (1 page, 11123 bytes).
Transcript written on c-sample_.log.
/usr/share/asymptote/plain_shipout.asy: 87.10: runtime: shipout failed
make[1]: *** [../Makerules:110: c-sample.pdf] Error 1
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction what to do? It looks like something is missing but I have no idea what :/

Complete build log is here: https://pastebin.com/dqJvTznK

Source code I'm trying to compile is here: https://github.com/graywolf/pruvodce

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should try and make a minimal example: you don't expect we clone your large repository and analyze it, do you?

Comment: @egreg tbh I'm not even sure where to start.. the text `\picture` doesn't even occur in the repository, not even once. So I was more hoping for few pointers I could try than for guaranteed solution..